# Passing variable to mysql query results in "function query on null"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a class that I am passing a query to, but the fatal error

> function query on null'

occurs when attempting to run the query.

I echoed $mysql_statement and got

```
select * from users
```

which is the intended query, but in the context of the query statement it keeps telling returning the fatal error `function query on null`.

Any ideas on why the "select * from users" that is legitimately stored in `$mysql_statement` is being interpreted as null?  (the properties used and not defined here are defined in a parent class):

The page.php:

```
<?php
include("includes/database_classes.php");

new database_connection;
new database_query("SELECT * FROM users");

?>
```

...and the database_classes.php:

```
<?php
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    class database_connection
    {   
        protected $username = 'root';
        protected $password = '';
        protected $hostname = 'localhost';
        protected $database = 'assistant';  
        protected $database_handle;

        function connect()
        {
            try
            {
                $database_handle = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
            }

            catch (PDOException $e) 
            {
                print "Error!: " . $e ->getMessage() . "<br/>";
                die();
            }
        }
    }

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
class database_disconnection extends database_connection
{
    function disconnect()
    {
        $database_handle = null;
    }
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    class database_query extends database_connection
    {
        protected $mysql_statement;

        function __construct( $mysql_statement )
        {
            $this->mysql_statement = $mysql_statement;

            echo $mysql_statement;

            foreach($this->database_handle->query("$mysql_statement")->fetch_assoc() as $row) {
                print_r($row);
            }
        }

    }

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: this is an array i suppose? `$this->database_handle->query("$mysql_statement")`

Comment: so basically your attribute database_handle is not getting initialised properly

Comment: You had better show us the `database_connection` class

Comment: @Akintunde he is getting null related problem, so once his database_handle variable gets sorted then he would be able to execute the query

Comment: Also show where you create database_query class.

Comment: I added the database_connection class to the post as requested.  I am not receiving an error on a disconnection class that has $database_handle = null; so I my thinking is that it was initialized correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure Riggs - wouldn't I get an error about the class instead of the null query?

Comment: I updated the post to include all the code for clarity's sake.  The database_disconnection does not toss the error, but the database_query does.

Comment: Wait - the function connect() code - this doesn't appear to be actually implemented(?) - meaning it looks like the function is never called, is this part of what may be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having problem when trying to loop through the result of your SQL query, this happened because, you didn't include method "fetch_assoc()"

Instead of:

```
foreach($this->database_handle->query("$mysql_statement") as $row);
```

Why not?

```
foreach($this->database_handle->query("$mysql_statement")->fetch_assoc() as $row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Alien Whale, but I'm still receiving the same error after using fetch.

Comment: Check if your connection is truly connected

Comment: Also, `$database_handle = new PDO(..)` has to read `$this->database_handle = new PDO(..)`

Comment: In your db connection class, `$database_handle = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);` you referred to variables not the the class properties you created, I hope you get me